# Publish docker container port and access that port from another docker container

Tags: postgresql, networking, docker, debian

I'm trying to run a [postgres container](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) with docker and access to it from another container.
Steps to reproduce:

- Run postgres container and publish port: `docker run -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test -d -p 5555:5432 postgres:9.6`
- Run other container to access to the postgres:

  `docker run -it debian /bin/bash
  apt-get update
  apt-get install telnet
  telnet 172.17.0.1 5555`

Result: `Trying 172.17.0.1...` and then fail.
But i can access it from the host with localhost or from outside with the public ip because the image allow all ip, and i am not blocking that port.
The ping works.

I have tested this in my machine and it works as expected, but i need to know why it is not working on this server.

Where can i start looking to know what i have wrong on my server?

**Update:**
I tried doing the telnet directly to the ip asigned to the postgres container(172.17.0.2) and i get the following error:

`telnet 172.17.0.2
Trying 172.17.0.2...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`

But ping still works at 172.17.0.2

Output of docker inspect on the postgres container:

```
docker inspect a379130e94f7
[
    {
        "Id": "a379130e94f7596ebe632e3ae825710c978577a3fb6b245a4f95374051eb8310",
        "Created": "2017-03-31T08:07:36.06939775Z",
        "Path": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "postgres"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 20283,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2017-03-31T08:07:37.257557864Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:9910dc9f2ac0dbc193abc4718984cb3ad48989fc02cac4b36ad3d6b7d5d781f9",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/a379130e94f7596ebe632e3ae825710c978577a3fb6b245a4f95374051eb8310/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/a379130e94f7596ebe632e3ae825710c978577a3fb6b245a4f95374051eb8310/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/a379130e94f7596ebe632e3ae825710c978577a3fb6b245a4f95374051eb8310/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/a379130e94f7596ebe632e3ae825710c978577a3fb6b245a4f95374051eb8310/a379130e94f7596ebe632e3ae825710c978577a3fb6b245a4f95374051eb8310-json.log",
        "Name": "/gallant_thompson",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "5432/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "5555"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": -1,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Name": "overlay",
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay/34f43052282b0bcba741b61cb812bc4e05d1d0045820c36781684e2f2f763b41/root",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay/904ec813189c55332d8cb5ee3dca74e211a0d42a4434f8a90e07b8a05f4d5c5b/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay/904ec813189c55332d8cb5ee3dca74e211a0d42a4434f8a90e07b8a05f4d5c5b/upper",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay/904ec813189c55332d8cb5ee3dca74e211a0d42a4434f8a90e07b8a05f4d5c5b/work"
            }
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "82dd5d73415e8142eb5bb985a9695f46772328f271ede839cbf55436917ed120",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/82dd5d73415e8142eb5bb985a9695f46772328f271ede839cbf55436917ed120/_data",
                "Destination": "/var/lib/postgresql/data",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "a379130e94f7",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "5432/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test",
                "PATH=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "GOSU_VERSION=1.7",
                "LANG=en_US.utf8",
                "PG_MAJOR=9.6",
                "PG_VERSION=9.6.2-1.pgdg80+1",
                "PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "postgres"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "postgres:9.6",
            "Volumes": {
                "/var/lib/postgresql/data": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "55c678dffab73ca25857667ddb003751494d32beb917abd1bba4d77f61071d9f",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "5432/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "5555"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/55c678dffab7",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "a0f845fa572fd6b15fc7c2ba74d3a302eb353e51ddbafb97d81e8858124808d7",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "16d30671a47d90037673ef30843421eaeeeba41028ec204a8fcea13ac8108f6d",
                    "EndpointID": "a0f845fa572fd6b15fc7c2ba74d3a302eb353e51ddbafb97d81e8858124808d7",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed your steps and for me it is working.

What you could try is inspect the container. First get it's name with:

```
docker ps
```

Then inspect the container with:

```
docker inspect CONTAINER_NAME
```

In my example it was docker inspect zealous_wright.
Here you can find the IP adress and port of the container, try to use this IP and port. If it's still not working maybe try assigning a port other then 5555. It could be usefull to share this inspect data of the container maybe we can see what's wrong.

UPDATE:

It probally has to do with proxies. I'm using DockerForMac so there were quite some differences but the one standing out was:

```
"no_proxy=*.local, 169.254/16"
```

I had this one and you didn't. When I removed this I got the same error as you. I changed this by going to:

Docker preferences -> Proxies -> Use system proxy, instead of No proxy.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I made a update. I tried with other ports and it happens the same. I don't have any port conflicts because i can access it from local or outside.